# Select recording device in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, audio-recording

How to select recording device in C++ , Windows. I want to record sound from PC, and I want a function in C++ which can select device: Line, Microphone or Stereo Mix. I dont know how to do that. Please show me example or give me links to learn this.

I found something related in C++, but it not working good:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=449213

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try is by calling the [waveInGetNumDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713732%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The waveInGetNumDevs function returns the number of waveform-audio
>   input devices present in the system.

```
UINT waveInGetNumDevs(VOID);
```

> Returns the number of devices. A return value of zero means that no
>   devices are present or that an error occurred.

Here is an example:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "mmsystem.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int _tmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[] )
{
    UINT deviceCount = waveInGetNumDevs();

    if ( deviceCount > 0 )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++ )
        {
            WAVEINCAPSW waveInCaps;    
            waveInGetDevCapsW( i, &waveInCaps, sizeof( WAVEINCAPS ) );

            //Your code here
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for example, but I meant other thing: How do I set the recording decive as default? For example when I start recording if default device is set as microphone then I'm not able to record from Stero Mix, but I need only  from Stereo Mix and before start recording I need to make it as default device in windows to allow me record from mixer.

Comment: hey! here a problem: sizeof( WAVEINCAPS ) must be sizeof( **WAVEINCAPSW** )

Comment: don't you think `if ( deviceCount > 0 )` is unnecessary. ?